# Why can't I cast an lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult to a string?

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

```
print(type(players[1]))


for player in players:
    player = str(player)

print(type(players[1]))
```

the output is:

```
 <class 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult'>
 <class 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult'>
```

I need to convert this ElementUnicode object into a string so that I can call substring on it, but this for loop isn't doing it. And when I cast it to a string and call substring at the same time, the console reads: str object has no object substring, which makes no sense.

```
 str(players[i]).substring()
```

Any thoughts on why that may be the case and how I could get around to calling substring on this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting `_ElementUnicodeResult` to `str` is not a problem. Complete demonstration:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = """
<root>
 <player>ABC</player>
 <player>DEF</player>
</root>"""

root = etree.fromstring(doc)
players = root.xpath("player/text()")

print(type(players[1]))

# Cast each player to a plain string 
players = [str(p) for p in players]

print(type(players[1]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult'>
<class 'str'>
```

---

In the question, you have the following code:

```
for player in players:
    player = str(player)

print(type(players[1]))
```

This does not change anything outside the `for` loop. `type(players[1])` will be the same as before.

In addition, it is true that `str` has no `substring` attribute. XPath has a `substring()` function. Maybe that is what you were thinking of?

Comment: this was back in high school so i forget **everything** relating to the context of this question. your answer seems right tho so here's an accept

Answer (score 0):

If you're running python2, try:  `unicode(players[i])`