# openpyxl can't handle writing lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult

Tags: lxml, openpyxl

This script is just for demonstration purposes, usually lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult type is given while parsing some data. For some reason, a string of this type can't be written to Excel using openpyxl. Is this some kind of a bug or expected behavior for this type of strings?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import lxml

string_to_write = lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult("just a string")

outfile = Workbook()
ws = outfile["Sheet"]

ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "just a string"
ws.cell(row=1, column=2).value = string_to_write

outfile.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Can't you just turn it into a regular string? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465761/407651

Comment: openpyxl is very conservative it comes to cell values, you must pass in a standard Python type that maps to something appropriate in Excel.